# How to use API returned image with background-image url

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, css-variables

I'm attempting to use API data as a background image using CSS variables with the background-image url property.

This is my html:

```
<script>
let imageQuery = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${show_info.backdrop_path})`
}
</script>
<div class="background-image">
    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{imageQuery}}">
</div>
```

//show_info.background_path points to the api data object

This is the css:

```
.background-image {
--backgroundImage: "";
background-image: var(--backgroundImage);
background-color: bisque;
padding-top: 200px;
padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `--backgroundImage: ""` ... do you expect an image? also, `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{imageQuery}` ... HTML doesn't "read" javascript variables - it's like you've got the first 10% of what you need, and then just simply stopped

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't read variables from JS, but JS could operate CSS, like this:

```
<html>

<body>
  <div id="background-image" class="background-image">
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  const imageDom = document.getElementById('background-image')
  imageDom.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url_from_your_API})`
</script>
<style>
  .background-image {
    background-color: bisque;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Is it too tedious?

That's why we use JSX and similar things.